# Lightning Component's Styling is not working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, stylesheets, internet-explorer

I have developed a Lightning component for the Menu section of our Community(Napili template). All the custom stylings are working well in Chrome, Safari, Firefox except for Internet Explorer. 
All the CSS stylings and responsive icons(which shows up at only specified resolutions) are being displayed like a shattered glass on a web-page.

Does anyone had this issue previously? To fix this issue, do I need to include any special packages/CDNs to have the same rendering as in different browsers?
Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: what version of IE?

Comment: Internet Explorer: IE 11

Comment: Hmm - IE 11 is supported - maybe you should report this (with a reproducible sample) to the Lightning Design People.

Comment: I am not only using SLDS pre-built Css, but added my custom Css file. But these custom stylings are working fine in other browsers except than IE. Weird.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. Did you found any solution ? I have implemented SLDS in my visualforce page. Will this( SLDS in VF page) be supported in IE11 ? And if it is supported, will this be supported after 2020 ?

Comment: I missed out few CSS inclusions that are specifically intended for IE. `/* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);` After adding such tags, it worked. I am not sure about 2020, hopefully we will have some fixes if the current config doesn't work.