# Lightning Component's Styling is not working in Internet Explorer 11 but work fine in Edge

Tags: lightning-design-system

i also have same problem its look seems correct in Microsoft edge but not in IE11 i tried to see weather its might efffect by 1-0f-1 followed by 1-0f-2 in class but its i get Lightning component is not working in IE11 but work fine in microsoft edge?? can i write custom css for IE

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
/* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
}
```

Or

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
  <!--[if IE]>
    This content is ignored in Internet Explorer 10 and other browsers.
    In older versions of Internet Explorer, it renders as part of the page.
  <![endif]-->
```

can i do this in lightning css

Comment: Lightning Component's Styling is not working in Internet Explorer? 
 i have gone thorough this question too ::
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175004/lightning-components-styling-is-not-working-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Your ideas won't work, because if you're running in IE 9 compatible mode, Lightning won't run, but if you run in IE 10 or higher mode, then conditional comments won't work. They are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I checked the latest [SF Release notes (Spring 18)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/getstart_browsers_sfx.htm?edition=&impact=) I found that
[image]

So it looks like SF has removed support for IE11. If you still opted for Extended Support then there are still significant performance issues in Lightning Experience.

So it might be the time when you need to update your browser.