# Lightning design Grid layout does not work in IE11

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, visualforce

i have a problem in IE11 grid layout slds-size-** which is making a grid as bad way but in other browser is great all working fine ..

```
<div class="slds-card__body">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-theme--default slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--12-of-12" >
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
                    <div class="slds-box slds-m-around--small slds-size--1-of-3 slds-medium-size--2-of-6 slds-large-size--3-of-12" 
                   >
                        <span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar--large slds-avatar--circle">
                          sample work
                        </span>
                        <h4> welcome</h4>
                        <a routerLink="album/{{album.id}}" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Album Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

so wat is wrong its only in IE11 not proper grid how can i solve this issue ??

Chrome  view
[image: Chrome view]
IEView
[image: IE view]

i have gone through this 
[Lightning Component's Styling is not working in Internet Explorer 11 but work fine in Edge](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206063/lightning-components-styling-is-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11-but-work-fi)

Comment: please keep in mind the following: [Recommendations and Requirements for All Browsers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browser_recommendations.htm&type=5)

Comment: i have checked  Considerations for Microsoft Internet Explorer  its all there which requirement is given by salesforce

Comment: Same here, did you find a solution?